# How can I delete a folder from .tar archive file?

Tags: php, phar, tarfile

I want to delete a directory from a TAR archive file. I used the PharData class but I don't know how delete a directory.

I tried the `Phardata::delete()` method, but it only destroys empty folders in the TAR file and cannot delete other folders.

I tried the code below to delete folders from ZIP files and that works well. This code didn't work in PharData objects. How can I do it in the TAR file?

```
private function deleteArchiveDirectory($directory){
    // When archive object is ZipArchive` 
    if ($this->archiveObject instanceof ZipArchive) { 
        $numFiles = $this->archiveObject->numFiles;   
        $folderToDelete = $directory;  //folder to delete relative to root
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; $i++) {     
            $entryInfo = $this->archiveObject->statIndex($i);
            if (substr($entryInfo["name"], 0, 
            strlen($folderToDelete)) == $folderToDelete) {
                $this->archiveObject->deleteIndex($i);
            }
        }
    }
    // When archive object is PharData
    if ($this->archiveObject instanceof PharData) {
        // How can I do it enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: _“but it only destroy empty folders in TAR file and can not delete other folders”_ - so have you tried emptying these folders before then, by deleting the files contained in them one by one …?

Comment: Phar::delete() can only delete empty folders, but I want to delete a folder with files cantained it. I don't want emptying the folder before.

Comment: Then I guess your choices are, a) you move to the parallel universe where what you want is possible, or b) you change this, rather arbitrary sounding “but I don’t want to” requirement, and just _do what is necessary_ to achieve your goal.